# sequential search in a string array issues

Tags: java, arrays, search, sequential

Relatively new to java. I'm trying to sequentially search in a string array but I'm pretty sure there's something wrong with my if statement because the boolean flag stays false. The code worked with the int array, so I don't understand what's wrong with this one.

```
public static void sequentialNameSearch(String[] array) {
    // sequential name search
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String value;
    int index = 0;
    boolean flag = false;
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter a name to search for");
    value = input.next();

    while (flag == false && index < array.length - 1) {
        if (array[index] == value) {
            flag = true;
            System.out.println(array[index] + " is number "
                + (index + 1) + " in the array.");
        }
        else if (index == array.length - 1)
            System.out.println("That name is not in the array");

        index++;
    }

    input.close();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is that you can't compare the contents of two Strings with ==.
For that, you should use equals() or equalsIgnoreCase() methods of one of the strings. Example:

```
if (array[index].equals(value)) {
```